# Estimation of DFT

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $a_1,a_2 \ldots a_n$ be a real-valued sequense with $a_i=O(N^{-1})$.
How do  I estimate Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of this sequence?

$$\hat{a}_{j}=\sum_{r=1}^{K}a_{r}\exp\Bigl(-2\pi ij\frac{r}{K}\Bigr),\qquad K=O(N^\alpha),\quad \alpha<1$$

Can I say that DFT sequence $\operatorname{Re}[\hat{a}_{i}]=O(N^{-1})$?

Comment: Do any of the objects depend on the number $N$?  It seems to be floating free.

Comment: $K=O(N^\alpha)$ with $\alpha<1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, if you mean an uniform bound in $j$. Here is the example:

Fix $j$ and define
$$
 a_r = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{N}, & Re(\exp(-2\pi i j r/ K)) \geq 0;\\\
 0, & otherwise.\end{cases}
$$
It is than easy to estimate that the number of $a_r = \frac{1}{N}$ is comparable to $K$. Even more is true, one has that the number of $a_r = \frac{1}{N}$ such that $Re(\exp(-2\pi i j r/ K)) \geq \sigma$ is comparable to $K$ for any $\sigma > 0$.

This implies that
$$
 Re(\hat{a}_j) \geq c N^{1 - \alpha}
$$
for some different $c$.